# Returning HTML with Azure Serverless Function req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, serverless-framework, serverless-architecture

I've got some TIF files in Azure Blob Storage. I'd like to display them in the browser via a link embedded in a spreadsheet. The simplest way to do this should be to take the file code as a request parameter and return the properly formatted HTML, right?

So right now I've got it returning a req.body with some HTML. Unfortunately, the HTML just shows up as a string in the browser. How do I make it render as HTML with minimal rigamarole?

Here's my code:

```
if (req.query.blob) {
    let blob = req.query.blob;
    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: `<object width=200 height=200 
                data="<baseaddress>/${blob}.tif" type="image/tiff">
                <param name="src" value="<baseaddress>/${blob}.tif">
                <param name="negative" value="yes">
                </object>`
    };
}
```

Comment: As I understand, this HTML result will be used as an iframe of your main page, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the headers to specify the **content type** to HTML and the response must be a **full valid HTML page** (with the `<html>` tag and the rest).

**Example**:

```
module.exports.hello = (event, context, callback) => {

  const html = `
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>The Page Title</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </body>
    </html>`;

  const response = {    
    statusCode: 200, 
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    }, 
    body: html
  };

  callback(null, response);
};
```

Comment: This example was tested on AWS, but I believe that it will be equivalent to Azure.